# Regex chain replacement issue

Tags: ruby, regex

I try to develop a **super basic** template language, and I have a problem with RegEx, I try to convert this:

```
# Tilte
## Subtitle
### Subsubtitle
Lorem ipsum b(dolor) sit i(amet), consectetur u(adipisicing) elit
```

to this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Subtilte</h2>
<h3>Subsubtitle</h3>
Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit <i>amet</i>, consectetur <u>adipisicing</u> elit
```

But I get this:

```
<h1></h1>
<h2>TEma 4</h2>
<h3>Subtitle</h3>
Lorem ipsum <strong>Subsubtitle</strong> sit i(amet), consectetur u(adipisicing) elit
```

Here is my code:

```
input = ARGV[0]

regExes = {

    h1: [/^# (.*)$/, "<h1>", "</h1>"],
    h2: [/^## (.*)$/, "<h2>", "</h2>"],
    h3: [/^### (.*)$/, "<h3>", "</h3>"],
    b: [/b\((.*)\)/, "<strong>", "</strong>"],

}

strFile = File.read input

puts "\t", strFile

for index, regEx  in regExes

    actualNode = regExes[index]
    print actualNode, "\n"
    strFile.gsub! actualNode[0], "#{actualNode[1]}#{$1}#{actualNode[2]}"

end

puts strFile
```

What should I do?

Comment: Use lazy matching: `/b\((.*?)\)/`

Comment: Ok, one thing is solved, but I still have the problems with **the h group tags**

Comment: **The problem is located in the values that are sets**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the regexes in this order (and mind the lazy matching with strong, underline and bold tags and the word boundary `\b` in front of each of those to make sure we do not match parts of words):

```
regExes = {

    h3: [/^### (.*)$/, "<h3>", "</h3>"],
    h2: [/^## (.*)$/, "<h2>", "</h2>"],
    h1: [/^# (.*)$/, "<h1>", "</h1>"],
    b: [/\bb\((.*?)\)/, "<strong>", "</strong>"],
    i: [/\bi\((.*?)\)/, "<i>", "</i>"],
    u: [/\bu\((.*?)\)/, "<u>", "</u>"],
}
```

and then use a non-destructive `gsub`:

```
input = input.gsub(actualNode[0], "#{actualNode[1]}\\1#{actualNode[2]}")
```

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/7Q3wZJ)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `gsub!` line try this...

```
strfile = actualNode[1]+actualNode[0].match(strfile)[1]+actualNode[2] if actualNode[0].match(strfile)
```

Comment: You included the part where I wrote `+actualNode[2]`? You scrolled to see the whole line?

Comment: I tested this in irb.